# innerHTML with getElementByClassName doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, hover

This one works:

```
<td onmouseover="document.getElementById('textbox').innerHTML='Hidden text'" onmouseout="document.getElementById('textbox').innerHTML='Show text'">
    <div id="textbox">Show text</div>
</td>
```

But this one doesn't:

```
<td onmouseover="document.getElementByClassName('textbox').innerHTML='Hidden text'" onmouseout="document.getElementByClassName('textbox').innerHTML='Show text'">
    <div class="textbox">Show text</div>
</td>
```

How can I fix this? I need a class to use it more than once.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What do querySelectorAll, getElementsByClassName and other getElementsBy\* methods return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-getelementsbyclassname-and-other-getelementsby-method)

Answer (score 10):

There's no `getElementByClassName` function but a [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/document.getElementsByClassName) one because there can be more than one element with a given class.

You could replace

```
 document.getElementByClassName('textbox')
```

with

```
 document.getElementsByClassName('textbox')[0]
```

**EDIT following the edit of your question :**

This function isn't available on IE8. If you want to use it on this browser, you must add a shim, such the one which is described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13261506/getelementsbyclassname-in-ie8).

Comment: Still doesn't work in my code. I updated the original question. It works in Chrome, Firefox etc but not IE8. `getElementById` works in IE8 but not `getElementsByClassName`, why?

Comment: Why ? The answer is in the link I gave : this function doesn't exist on IE8.

Comment: Aah, sorry. Didn't read the support-table first. How can I get this to work in IE8? Thx for helping me. :)

Answer (score 2):

It's `getElementsByClassName`. Note the plural `s` after `Element`.

And since it's an array you need to specify the index number.

```
document.getElementsByClassName('class-name')[0].innerHTML = 'html text'
```

And if you need to apply the change for every element, use a for loop.

```
for(i in document.getElementsByClassName('class-name')){
    document.getElementsByClassName('class-name')[i].innerHTML = 'html text';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can use jQuery, it's simpler using [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html2):

```
$("#textbox").html("Hidden text") // id=textbox
$(".textbox").html("Hidden text") // class=textbox
```

Comment: $("#textbox").html("Hidden text") is use for getting an object with reference ID not for class . for class you should use like this $(".textbox").html("Hidden text")

Comment: @ShashankShukla You're right, I edited the answer and added class selector vs. id selector. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That's because `getElementsByClassName` is returning an array of elements. You can try

```
document.getElementsByClassName('textbox')[0].innerHTML='Hidden text'
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you use document.querySelector:

```
<td onmouseover="document.querySelector('.textbox').innerHTML='Hidden text'" onmouseout="document.querySelector('.textbox').innerHTML='Show text'">
    <div class="textbox">Show text</div>
</td>
```

This one works I think.

There is something else that you should have in mind. Adding such things inside your html is not really good idea. That's because every time you are executing something. It will be good to cache the result of document.querySelector or document.getElementsByClassName. Imagine what will happen if you have 1000 rows inside your table. Here is a jsfiddle showing how you can improve the performance of the code http://jsfiddle.net/krasimir/Zbgng/2/

HTML

```
<table><tr>
<td class="table-column">
    column1
</td>
<td class="table-column">
    column2
</td>
<td class="table-column">
    column3
</td>
</tr></table>

<div class="textbox">Show text</div>
<div class="textbox">Show text</div>
<div class="textbox">Show text</div>
```

JS

```
var columns = document.querySelectorAll(".table-column");
var textboxes = document.querySelectorAll(".textbox");
for(var i=0; column=columns[i]; i++) {
    column.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
        replaceText("Hidden text");
    });
    column.addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
        replaceText("Show text");
    });
}
var replaceText = function(str) {
    for(var i=0; field=textboxes[i]; i++) {
        field.innerHTML = str;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it works in IE8? I need something to work in IE8 and other (newer) browsers.

Comment: I'm not able to test it right now, but the most critical part is querySelectorAll, which is supported by IE8 -> http://caniuse.com/queryselector
So, it should work.
It is supported in all the browsers nowadays.

Comment: This one doesn't work in IE8. Tested it right now via jsfiddle iFrame.

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementByClassName('whatever')` returns array of html object elements inside the document,

so you need

```
var ele = document.getElementsByClassName('textbox');

ele[0].innerHTML = "Whatever text" ;
```

If you want to set inner html to all the elements of this class
you can use

```
for(var i=0;i<ele.length;i++)
{
  ele[i].innerHTML = "we all are of same class";
  // or you can dynamically insert different text too    
}
```