# alterrnate for accesing the DOM element

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, checkbox

I have a situation where I need to access the header checkbox of the table 
I'm doing it with

```
document.getElementsByClassName("table_th_label_div")[0];
```

But as some of the older browser does not support .getElementsByClassName I need an alternative appproach for the same

Kindly Help
Thanks in advance

Comment: IE8 supports `querySelectorAll` (sort of)

Comment: Can you please tell me reason for down voting it.?

Comment: I suppose because your question doesn't show research on your part. There are a few dups http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9568969/getelementsbyclassname-ie8-object-doesnt-support-this-property-or-method, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13261506/getelementsbyclassname-in-ie8, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10484467/ie-8-object-doesnt-support-property-or-method-getelementsbyclassname

Answer (score 2):

This [solution](http://robertnyman.com/2008/05/27/the-ultimate-getelementsbyclassname-anno-2008/) may help. This is the getElementsByClassName function implemented in pure javascript, that works in IE.

```
/*
    Developed by Robert Nyman, http://www.robertnyman.com
    Code/licensing: http://code.google.com/p/getelementsbyclassname/
*/  
var getElementsByClassName = function (className, tag, elm){
    if (document.getElementsByClassName) {
        getElementsByClassName = function (className, tag, elm) {
            elm = elm || document;
            var elements = elm.getElementsByClassName(className),
                nodeName = (tag)? new RegExp("\\b" + tag + "\\b", "i") : null,
                returnElements = [],
                current;
            for(var i=0, il=elements.length; i<il; i+=1){
                current = elements[i];
                if(!nodeName || nodeName.test(current.nodeName)) {
                    returnElements.push(current);
                }
            }
            return returnElements;
        };
    }
    else if (document.evaluate) {
        getElementsByClassName = function (className, tag, elm) {
            tag = tag || "*";
            elm = elm || document;
            var classes = className.split(" "),
                classesToCheck = "",
                xhtmlNamespace = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml",
                namespaceResolver = (document.documentElement.namespaceURI === xhtmlNamespace)? xhtmlNamespace : null,
                returnElements = [],
                elements,
                node;
            for(var j=0, jl=classes.length; j<jl; j+=1){
                classesToCheck += "[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' " + classes[j] + " ')]";
            }
            try {
                elements = document.evaluate(".//" + tag + classesToCheck, elm, namespaceResolver, 0, null);
            }
            catch (e) {
                elements = document.evaluate(".//" + tag + classesToCheck, elm, null, 0, null);
            }
            while ((node = elements.iterateNext())) {
                returnElements.push(node);
            }
            return returnElements;
        };
    }
    else {
        getElementsByClassName = function (className, tag, elm) {
            tag = tag || "*";
            elm = elm || document;
            var classes = className.split(" "),
                classesToCheck = [],
                elements = (tag === "*" && elm.all)? elm.all : elm.getElementsByTagName(tag),
                current,
                returnElements = [],
                match;
            for(var k=0, kl=classes.length; k<kl; k+=1){
                classesToCheck.push(new RegExp("(^|\\s)" + classes[k] + "(\\s|$)"));
            }
            for(var l=0, ll=elements.length; l<ll; l+=1){
                current = elements[l];
                match = false;
                for(var m=0, ml=classesToCheck.length; m<ml; m+=1){
                    match = classesToCheck[m].test(current.className);
                    if (!match) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (match) {
                    returnElements.push(current);
                }
            }
            return returnElements;
        };
    }
    return getElementsByClassName(className, tag, elm);
};
```

Comment: Yes, I understand. But the solution is too long and can't reflect good in direct answer. So that's why I given him solution in link. And Its work.

Comment: Thanks Quantas. But again if users go to this link then they will fully understand the concept of how it is working. But anyways thanks.

Comment: Sure, that's why you have the link in the first place. But if one day the person doesn't renew their domain, then this answer would be useless, which is why it's preferred to have the main point (in this case the code) in the answer.